# scala function variables can not vary

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion

I have several lines of scala code which define a functionA that calls functionB repeatedly until n is zero(does functionB n times). Every iteration n decreases by 1, and x0 is updated as mentioned.

```
def functionA(c: Double, x0: Double, n: Int): Double = {
    require(x0>0) //This is a must
    while(n>0){
       x0=functionB(c, x0) //functionB predefined
       n--
    }
   x0
}
```

The problem is that the variables seem not able to change, as lines

```
x0=functionB(c, x0)
n--
```

are returning errors. If the current structure is not changed and total number of line remains the same, how can I do write the lines right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function parameters are `val`s in Scala, so you cannot modify them.

Write your function recursively. Something like:

```
def functionA(c: Double, x0: Double, n: Int): Double = {
  require(x0 > 0) //This is a must
  if (n < 0) {
    x0
  } else {
    functionA(c, functionB(c, x0), n - 1)
  }
}
```

Comment: Would this qualify for tail recursion optimisation?

Comment: It should as the last line is the recursive call. (Perhaps better to let the Scala compiler validate our intention with the `@tailrec` annotation!)

Comment: It depends. If it were in an `object` yes. If it were `private`, yes. If it were `final`, yes. Otherwise no 'cause the compiler cannot know that it is not overridden in a subtype.